# Javascript Find Numbers Near From String

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I have a list like this:

https://haxified.is-a-me.me/0a94f61d.png

and I want to find the three closest one, so for instance if I run
`1539, 4502`
it would find the three closest values to it, by closest I mean most similar for the first and second values of the string (separated by the comma)

I have tried doing a for loop, and working out the distance between all of them, but it didnt work.

Comment: post code please

Comment: Can you at least share an example output?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not in a good format. You would need an array of arrays of numbers, not an array of strings. So the first task is to make that conversion.

Then you could use the distance formula to calculate the distance to the given coordinates, and store that as an extra information with each point in the list.

Then sort by that additional distance. Sorting it is not the most efficient method, as you could retrieve the minimum distance first, then retrieve the minimum after removing the first, and finally retrieve the minimum again after removing the first minima found. But if you are interested in such optimisation, have a try yourself.

After sorting, slice the first three elements out of the resulting array and return that. You may want to convert those three items back to the original format, i.e. an array of three strings.

Here is a snippet:

```js
function closestThree(data, px, py) {
    return data
        .map( s => s.split(',').map(Number) ) // Convert to pairs of numbers
        .map( ([x,y]) => [x,y,(x-px)*(x-px)+(y-py)*(y-py)] ) // Add squared distance
        .sort( (a, b) => a[2] - b[2] ) // Sort by distance
        .slice(0, 3) // Get three first results
        .map( ([x, y]) => x + ',' + y ); // Convert back to strings
}

// Sample
const points = ['123,5432', '432,325', '735,1045', '583,564'];
const res = closestThree(points, 405, 630);
console.log(res);
```